# Basic explanation of Riemann Manifolds, transformations, etc

Tags: general-topology, terminology, riemannian-geometry, math-history

I would like to get your support for one particular aim. I would like to make a very simple presentation on Riemann manifolds, structure preserving transformations and the like to an audience of laymen, and I would like to particularly focus on topology, on simple things like homomorphisms of figures, letters and the like.

So I guess my question is very simple: How would you define /introduce Riemann manifolds in that context?

Best regards,and thanks in advance

Comment: If you want to focus on topology, you don't really need the notion of a Riemannian manifold/Riemannian metric. (Maybe I misunderstand what you mean.)

Comment: I want to illustrate to the whole stuff about orientation preserving in the manifolds. Therefore the connection to topology, I guess